# How can I add a view to at the bottom of a TabHost with layout params?

Tags: android, layout, admob, android-tabhost

I want to add an Adview at the bottom of a TabHost. But I can't figure out the params

```
final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "my Id");
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    tabHost.addView(adView,???layoutparams????);

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost
                .newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator("Documents"
```

edit: The ad is showing fine with `tabHost.addView(adView)` but its in the middle of the tab view. i want to position it at the bottom but i cant get the layout params to work

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be adding your AdView to the TabHost. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html), the TabHost widget should only contain a set of tab labels and a FrameLayout for displaying the contents of each tab. I think you should instead ensure that your TabHost is itself within a vertical LinearLayout (or similar), then you can add the AdView to the bottom of that LinearLayout rather than to the TabHost.

EDIT: What LayoutParams have you already tried? Have you tried using FrameLayout.LayoutParams or any other types? What is the root layout element of that individual tab?

Comment: Though, I haven't used admob and I don't know what AdView actually is!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the ad WITHIN your tab, define your custom tab layout (your_tab_layout.xml)

```
// get layoutinflater
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

// inflate your layout into a View
View tabView = LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_tab_layout);

// get your AdView from the layout
AdView adView = tabView.findViewById(R.id.your_adview_id);

// Add the tab
TabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator(tabView).setContent(intent);
```

I agree with @Scott, this does seem odd and I might be misunderstanding the question.  If you want the ad below your tabs, please disregard this answer, @Scott has it right.

Comment: The ad is showing fine with `tabHost.addView(adView)` but its in the middle of the tab view. i want to position it at the bottom but i cant get the layout params to work

Comment: please see @Scott answer, this is the right answer.  Put this in your layout below TabHost.